# SQLite update set value BLOB specific bytes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update a rather large DB and need a specific value to be updated from

```
00 00 00 00 00
```

to be

```
00 00 00 00 01
```

The issue being that the value type is changing from BLOB to TEXT when I perform the update using the commands below

```
update tablename
set "value" = 1
where name = "RowName";
```

Is there an easy way to specify blob(value)? values(), blob() and 'as blob' are yielding syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465'

So... something like

```
UPDATE table SET value = X'0000000001' WHERE name = 'RowName';
```